# Retrofit SocketTimeOutException in sending multiparty or JSON data in android

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Facing problem in sending a Mutipart or JSON data through retrofit lib

Retrofit Interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/v1/protected/updateprofile")
void uploadPhoto(@Part("name") String name,
                 @Part("image") TypedFile file,
                 Callback<ApiResponseModel> callback);
```

Adapter Code

```
private RestApi restApi;
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setClient(new OkClient(getClient())).setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson)).setRequestInterceptor(interceptor).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(Config.baseUrl).build();
        restApi = restAdapter.create(RestApi.class);
```

Error Log Generated after sending JSON request

> 

```
D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR http://www.example.com/api/v1/protected/addfriends
11-05 11:22:18.594  13384-15325/com.veddislabs.plicx D/Retrofit﹕ java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
            at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:258)
            at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:206)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:153)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:189)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:676)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:426)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:371)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:466)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
            at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:136)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
            at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
            at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:206)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:153)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:189)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:676)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:426)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:371)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:466)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I have tried to increase the timeout of the request in Request Adapter

```
  private OkHttpClient getClient() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return client;
    }
```

Comment: Check out the below answer link, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69376324/5068349

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have this error a few days ago and I discovered that your solution is correct but add more time

```
private OkHttpClient getClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    return client;
}
```

---

### For OkHttp3

```
 private OkHttpClient getClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();
    return client;
}
```

Comment: That's why I posted out the things that I have tried.

Comment: Well, this is just not a solution! You have to impliment an request retry mechanism not give it more time...

Comment: @Choletski The main problem is the time, because the request is not always fail, you can't restrict the user to upload very small file sizes when his bandwidth is very low

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was from the server side.

I had to disable `tcp_timestamp` by changing `sysctl` configuration on the API server. Also, if you have other services working over TCP on the same machine i.e. Redis etc., you should watch out for how this affects them.

Found this from an [issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1037) on Github.